# Deploy image from github actions to dockerhub and digital ocean

Tags: docker, github-actions, digital-ocean, dockerhub

I am trying to push an image built in my github actions workflow file to dockerhub but i am hit with the following error.

```
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/${{IMAGE_NAME}}]
d0a926aebfe9: Preparing
485962c8ac42: Preparing
acc19e4b4ad4: Preparing
d5b0419f251d: Preparing
2f0fce789923: Preparing
28def5cfb9ad: Preparing
8b3510de6162: Preparing
c57b67e296a6: Preparing
24302eb7d908: Preparing
28def5cfb9ad: Waiting
8b3510de6162: Waiting
c57b67e296a6: Waiting
24302eb7d908: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

This is my workflow file.

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        env:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        run: echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }} | docker login  docker.io -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }} --password-stdin"

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${{secrets.IMAGE_NAME}}:latest
      - name: Tag the image to latest
        run: docker tag ${{secrets.IMAGE_NAME}}:latest ${{secrets.IMAGE_NAME}}:latest
      - name: Image push
        run: docker push ${{secrets.IMAGE_NAME}}
```

The error I am getting from my workflow is  **denied: requested access to the resource is denied**

I appreciate any pointer on how to go about this.

Comment: Look at the image name in the push logs: you have an issue of variable evaluation so you're trying to push to literally `${{IMAGE_NAME}}` on DockerHub and you don't have the right there. As long as the push is not referring an image like `<username>/<repo>` it won't work.

Comment: BTW there are docker action in the market place for build and push multiple tags.

Comment: I also recommend OP uses the docker login action https://github.com/docker/login-action

Comment: does your repo for the image exist? do you have the right credentials?